# convergent sequence in quadratic mean and distrubutional sense?

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, distribution-theory

"Say if the following sequence of functions in R:
f_n(x) =
{
0, if |x| < n;
exp(−|x|/n), if |x| > n.
converges (1) in quadratic mean, (2) in the sense of distributions."

My own calculation of (1) says that it does converge in the quadratic mean, but I dont have the solutions for this problem so I dont know if I am right, I also need help for (2).

Comment: "In the sense of distributions" means $\int f_n g \to 0$ for any test function (i.e. continuous compact support) $g$. As $\int f_n g $ is eventually $0$, this is obvious.